# Track name of SSRS report running from portal

Tags: reporting-services

I have SPID that is blocking other processes.
If i do who2 on it, iam getting general details as SSRS report running using Service accounts.

I couldn't be able to track down to the report to see what report was that one ran manually on portal.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that I know of to do this directly unless you can narrow it down via a workstation or user.

However, you could look in the execution logs for reports that are running or were running during the timeframe you want.

Something like this could be adapted to look at the timeframe you need.

I've only included basic columns but there are plenty more available. This will show the report path and name, the user who ran it, the parameters used, and various stats about how long each stage of the report took.

```
use ReportServer
GO
SELECT c.[Path], c.Name, e.TimeStart, e.TimeDataRetrieval, e.TimeProcessing, e.TimeRendering, e.TimeEnd, e.UserName,  c.Parameter
    FROM [Catalog] c 
    JOIN ExecutionLog e on c.ItemID = e.ReportID
    WHERE TimeStart > '2024-03-06 11:18:00'
```